# Page Conversations API: Error Message for More than 2 Responses

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on building an app that (among other things) uses the Facebook Graph API for Pages to reply to direct messages to a page.  I send a POST request to `/CONVERSATION_ID/messages` as per the documentation, and everything seems to be working well.

The problem I'm encountering is that the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#conversations) claims

> "Also, a page can respond not more than twice to a user's message before the user has replied back,"

but I'm not seeing this happen during my testing.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#conversations

I've so far sent 4 responses to the message initiated by the Facebook user that I am using to test my app with, and the Graph API has not yet given me an error message.  The documentation also does not say what error message is supposed to be returned if a page attempts to send more than 2 responses to a message before the user replies back.

Does anyone know what the error message is that the Graph API returns when a page attempts to send more than 2 responses to a message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have found the answer to my own question.  While I could not find official documentation for the error messages, I found unofficial documentation for them at:

http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/Error_codes

The error code I was looking for was there:

```
 User has sent too many messages
```